# How to change variable in html template DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I wrote this variable(refactor) in my context dict.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def lessont(request, id):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ChapterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_chapter = Chapter.objects.create(lesson_id=id)
        new_chapter.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        new_chapter.description = form.cleaned_data['description']
        new_chapter.document = form.cleaned_data['document']
        new_chapter.save()
        return redirect('/lessont/lesson/<int:id>')
get_lessons = Lesson.objects.get(id=id)
get_chapter = Chapter.objects.all().filter(lesson=id)
get_group = StudentsGroup.objects.all().filter(lessons=id)
form = ChapterForm()
refactor = False
refactor_id = 0
context = {
    'get_lesson': get_lessons,
    'get_chapter': get_chapter,
    'get_group': get_group,
    'form': form,
    'refactor': refactor,   <----- HERE
    'refactor_id': refactor_id,
}
template = 'core/lessont.html'
return render(request, template, context) <----- pass it here
```

Then in my HTML template, I have an access to "refactor" variable and I want to change it by clicking the button

```
<button type="submit" name="button">Add</button>
```

I want to make something like:

```
<button type="submit" name="button" onClick={set "refactor" to True}>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `refactor` is the value of a dict and not a variable.

For manage it in the django template you can try one of those:

- pass `locals()` instead of `context` if you want to use the variable and not the dict
- if you want to use `context` as a dict, in the template you must use `{{context.refactor}}` for take the value ([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups))
- If you are using external utils like [sw-django-utils](https://github.com/telminov/sw-django-utils), consider to use [get_key_from_dict](https://github.com/telminov/sw-django-utils/blob/master/djutils/templatetags/djutils.py)